# How to do configuration of PostgreSQL database in DHIS2?

Tags: windows, postgresql, dhis-2

I've downloaded and executed DHIS-2 in the Windows operating system. I want to connect with a PostgreSQL database. I'm trying the below configuration settings in the `dhis.conf` file but it's not working.

```
connection.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
connection.url = jdbc:postgresql:dhis2
connection.username = dhis
connection.password = dhis
connection.schema = update
encryption.password = abcd
```

It's showing me following error message.

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
```

Comment: This question lacks information, especially a question. You don't provide an error message, some code, nor a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you give an error message ?

Comment: Check the logfiles of that application and make sure Postgres runs on the same server where your application is running ("localhost"), otherwise you have to change the JDBC URL.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that the database name, username and password is correct.

You can test this on the command line / terminal with the following command:

```
psql -d dhis2 -U dhis -p
```

Then enter your password. If you cannot connect, one or more of database name, username and password are incorrect.